# Binary to char converting in c

Tags: c, binary, char

I have been trying to convert a binary number into a char, I use the following code to convert the char into binary:

```
void bin(char x){
    int y;
    for(y = 0; y < sizeof(char) * 8; y++){
    fprintf(f2,"%c", ( x & (1 << y) ) ? '1' : '0' );
}}
```

And it works fine.

The problem is that I don't know how to undo it, I want to get this binary number and convert it to the initial char. I'm using the folliwing code but it generates a core problem.

```
char subbuff[9];
memcpy( subbuff, &fichero[0], 8 );
subbuff[8] = '\0';


for(int k=8;k<fichero_len;k+=8){        

    char c = strtol(subbuff, 0, 2);
    printf("%s = %c = %d = 0x%.2X\n", subbuff, c, c, c);
    memcpy( subbuff, &fichero[k], k+8 );
    subbuff[8] = '\0';  

}
```

for exaple if i convert the string "hola" the first code shows "00010110111101100011011010000110"

but if i put that into the second code:

```
const char *hola="00010110111101100011011010000110";
char subbuff[16];
memcpy( subbuff, hola[0], 8 );
subbuff[8] = '\0';


for(int k=8;k<strlen(hola);k+=8){   
    char c = strtol(subbuff, 0, 2);
    printf("%s = %c = %d = 0x%.2X\n", subbuff, c, c, c);
    memcpy( subbuff, &hola[k], k+8 );
    subbuff[8] = '\0';  

}
```

it generates a core problem

Comment: Please show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are copying at least 16 bytes into `char subbuff[9]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

One problem is that you are copying too many bytes into `subbuff` with

```
memcpy( subbuff, &fichero[k], k+8 );
```

Another is that you pass a bad pointer to `memcpy` with

```
memcpy( subbuff, hola[0], 8 );
```

which will cause a segfault. **Please enable compiler warnings.**

There is no need even to do that first, outside of the loop. It can be done similar like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *hola = "01101000011011110110110001100001";
    char subbuff[9];
    char result [256] = "";
    unsigned char c;
    int k;
    int index = 0;
    int fichero_len = (int)strlen(hola);

    for(k = 0; k < fichero_len; k += 8) {    
        memcpy(subbuff, &hola[k], 8);                   // <--- copy 8 butes only
        subbuff[8] = '\0';  
        c = (unsigned char)strtol(subbuff, 0, 2);
        printf("%s = %c = %d = 0x%.2X\n", subbuff, c, c, c);
        result[index++] = c;
        result[index] = '\0';
    }
    printf("Result = %s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally your bit sequences are reversed, so you won't get the `char` back that you started with!

**EDIT 2:** after adding a few lines to the above code and reversing the bits in the `hola` definition, I get this output. Obviously you must make sure that `result[]` is long enough.

Program output:

```
01101000 = h = 104 = 0x68
01101111 = o = 111 = 0x6F
01101100 = l = 108 = 0x6C
01100001 = a = 97 = 0x61
Result = hola
```

Comment: ok, now it works without the error but as you said it does not seem the original text

Comment: That is because you send bits 0 thru 7 to the output, you must send bits 7 thru 0.

Comment: `for(y = CHAR_BIT-1; y >= 0; y--)`

Comment: sorry, i don't understand

Comment: Just as you write a decimal number with the most significant digit on the left, so do you write a binary number with the most sig bit on the left. You send  bit 0 to the output first. So your bit patterns are reversed. The `y` loop I just commented, sends the bits in the correct order: MS. bit first. `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a byte, to be found in `limits.h`. OTOH my loop does not use `sizeof(char)` because it is *always* 1 by definition.

Comment: One last question, how i get all the char concatented in one big char? i'm using strcat and i get an error.